# ASCII in C++ Builder XE

Tags: ascii, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe

I want to make an application in Embarcadero C++ Builder XE  totally in ASCII but C++ Builder XE's VCL are now UNICODE base.

Anybody has any kind of idea that how can I do that

If any Preprocessor Directives or anything else

I want to use sqlite3 as a backend, but all the code examples I see use ASCII and the Unicode doesn't work for me.

I've been Googleing it for couple of days but didn't find any solution

Comment: Why do you insist on using ASCII instead of Unicode?

Comment: @ Frank Schmitt Because i want to use sqlite3 as back-end of that application & i am new to sqlite & all the tutorials & books i found are teaching ASCII so i totally don't know how to use it in UNICODE, i have posted for  its tutorial here some days back but know one had reply it.   So in the frustration i decide   to go back to ASCII if you know some tutorial about C++ Builder XE & Sqlite 3 Please help me thanks for your reply

Comment: note that the correct tag for C++ builder is <c++builder>, not two separate tags <c++> and <builder>

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AnsiString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.AnsiString) string classes, the different VCL strings convert without problems between each other. If you have a [UnicodeString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.UnicodeString) and want to access the character array as regular 8 bit characters instead of the `wchar_t` datatype you can use the [`t_str()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.UnicodeString.t_str) function instead of the [`c_str()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.UnicodeString.c_str).

I would however suggest that you looked at the [`UTF8String`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.UTF8String) class, it is one of the most interesting of the string classes because it is backwards compatible with 7-bit ASCII as well as giving you the possibility of supporting international characters.

Comment: UTF8String has some issues, I'd stick with Ansistring for English text.

Comment: @Johan Out of curiosity, which issues are we talking about?

Comment: for starters, in Delphi 2007 (or 2006, I forgot) UTF8string is defined as ansistring, in Delphi XE, it's still ansistring, but associated with codepage 65001, and `WideCharToMultiByte(65001) is called to convert the string from UTF-16 to UTF-8.` so code will not work the same depending on the version of Delphi you're in.